# Winbugs plots in latex

Tags: plot

I conducted a bayesian analysis and obtained some plots in winbugs. Does any one how to put the history graphs in WinBUGS in Latex? I could not save the plots as pdf.

Comment: Maybe virtually print the plots with software like CutePDF and by \includegraphics or pdfpage include the graph in your Latex file?

Comment: @Günal save/export the figure data in ascii .txt and plot in any software you like to get a PDF or EPS. May be combination of [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/FAQ.html). I suggest post your question at [Cross Validated.SX](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winbugs)

Comment: As it stands, this seems to be about WinBUGS (for which we could do with a link) rather than about TeX. It's borderline for on-topic. It would be useful if you could specify if th key part is to get the data out of WinBUGS or to reproduce the same type of graphic using LaTeX.

Answer (score 7):

Can you save/export the plots in any other format? If yes, maybe you can convert those files to pdf using programs like ImageMagick or Inkscape but, as far as I remember, WinBUGS is very limited for editing or exporting plots.

Another option is using R. You can export from WinBUGS all your data in ASCII and in R you can import them with the package coda. There also is a package called R2WinBUGS, I do not know how it works but it could be useful (it seems you can run your BUGS model from R). The advantage of using R is that it has a lot of functions to create beautiful plots and you can save them in pdf easily (or in tikz format with the package tikzDevice, if you want).

I hope this helps you.